# Why are the results loading from the db, instead of cache?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, memcached

When I run:

```
IpPermission.blacklist.pluck(:ip)
```

I get the results:

```
=> ["127.0.0.11012q", "50.36.46.48"]
```

If I manually change any of the rows in the ip_permissions table, and run `IpPermission.blacklist.pluck(:ip)` again. It displays the updated results. Shouldn't it load the results from cache and not directly from the db?

My model looks like:

```
class IpPermission < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_presence_of :ip, :note, :category
  validates_uniqueness_of :ip, :scope => [:category]
  validates :category, :inclusion => { :in => ['whitelist', 'blacklist'] }

  def self.whitelist
    Rails.cache.fetch('whitelist', :expires_in => 1.month) { self.where(:category => 'whitelist') }
  end

  def self.blacklist
    Rails.cache.fetch('blacklist', :expires_in => 1.month) { self.where(:category => 'blacklist') }
  end
end
```

Comment: I hope you are in development trying out these things, can you let  me know what is the value of `config.action_controller.perform_caching` in your development.rb file?

Comment: Can you try setting it to `true` and restarting the server? and see whether if it works?

Comment: Still the same result. It is not getting it from cache. Also testing this on our staging env. Same.

Comment: Yeap 3.2.8, and still the same result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this should solve our problem:

Change this

```
  def self.whitelist
    Rails.cache.fetch('whitelist', :expires_in => 1.month) { self.where(:category => 'whitelist') }
  end

  def self.blacklist
    Rails.cache.fetch('blacklist', :expires_in => 1.month) { self.where(:category => 'blacklist') }
  end
```

to this

```
  def self.whitelist
    Rails.cache.fetch('whitelist', :expires_in => 1.month) { self.where(:category => 'whitelist').all }
  end

  def self.blacklist
    Rails.cache.fetch('blacklist', :expires_in => 1.month) { self.where(:category => 'blacklist').all }
  end
```

The where does not make the actual query, if you put `.all` then you make the query, so you are not storing the data but you just storing the query

Comment: Perfect! Yea it seemed, it was caching the ActiveRelation instead of the results. Thanks for that!